# How to deal with reusable components and a pinia store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

We are working on a project where multiple teams will be using some reusable components. These components will be using a pinia store. This pinia store will be defined in the individual project.
What is the best practice for passing in and modifying data in the pinia store in these reusable components? Can the whole store be passed in as a prop? Will we lose some benefits of pinia in doing so?

Comment: The question is too unspecific. It may or may not be a good practice to pass a store as a prop. This is a form of DI that could possibly be justified. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com is more suited for the design questions